# Regex.IsMatch freezes

Tags: c#

I have code:

```
string pattern =
            @"^(((://)?([A-Za-z0-9\.,\(\)\?\-!@#$%\^&\*=_\+\[\]\{\}\\""';><~\| \n\t:]+(/|://)?)*[A-Za-z0-9\.,\(\)\?\-!@#$%\^&\*=_\+\[\]\{\}\\""';><~\| \n\t]))$";

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

string message =
            "THINGS IN THIS MESSAGE ARE\r\n";

regex.IsMatch(message); // <- freezes

Console.ReadKey();
```

It freezes on regex.IsMatch. When I change

```
message = "THINGS IN THIS MESSAGE ARE\n";
```

regex.IsMatch returns value.

Why does IsMatch freezes?

Comment: In my Pc it took ~24 seconds to run, your pattern is very complex and requires a lot of calculations. What do you want to match? Maybe we can simplify it.

Comment: Any time a regular expression seems to freeze it is generally due to what is called [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). This can be improved by reducing the complexity of your regular expression and introducing better anchors and/or quantifier hints.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html and http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding `\r` in the last section works for me. It should be:

```
... | \n\r\t]))$
```

Not:

```
... | \n\t]))$
```

Test:

```
string pattern =
    @"^(((://)?([A-Za-z0-9\.,\(\)\?\-!@#$%\^&\*=_\+\[\]\{\}\\""';><~\| \n\t:]+(/|://)?)*[A-Za-z0-9\.,\(\)\?\-!@#$%\^&\*=_\+\[\]\{\}\\""';><~\| \n\r\t]))$";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string message = "THINGS IN THIS MESSAGE ARE\r\n";
regex.IsMatch(message);
```

Comment: Pattern can not be changed. It comes from xsd file. '\r' is not allowed.